# How to filter empty fields in the view?

Tags: php, javascript

I need to display a page with detailed information about a product. e.g.

```
 <ul>
 <li>Product: <?php echo $product['Product']['name'] ?></li>
 <li>Features: <?php echo $product['Product']['Features'] ?></li>
```

etc. (may be 20-30 fields)

The problem is that each product may have or may not have blank fields and I only need to show not empty fields to user.

How to properly filter results to generate and show only

```
<li>
```

that contain information?

I see 3 approaches.

1. Many and many of

   ```
   <?php if (!empty($product['Product']['name']) echo "<li>Product: ".$product['Product']['name']."</li>"?>
   ```
2. Add some kind of JS filtering (I don't know JS so it may be impossible to achieve)
3. Add another column to DB with "li" field description

   ```
   (<li>Product:)
   ```

   and then somehow output only not empty fields with While loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($product['Product'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($product['Product'][$key] != '') {
            if ($key == 'Info') {
                echo '<li>Some text that describes information for a user: ' . $value . '</li>';
            }
            else {
                echo '<li>' . $key . ': ' . $value . '</li>';
            }
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: But with this approach I loose my description field which follows li tag in the example.

Comment: Where you store the description field? Isn't in the $product['Product'] array?

Comment: My english is definitely very bad, sorry. I'll try to describe situation in the other words. I need to display: <li> Some text that describes information for a user: <?php echo $product['Product']['Info']?> </li>

Answer (score 0):

I would consider wrapping option 1 in a helper function:

```
function printProductListItem($value)
{
    if (!empty($value) 
        echo "<li>Product: " . $value . "</li>";
}
```

And call it like this:

```
printProductListItem($product['Product']['name']);
```